# Will cross validation give a biased estimate of out of sample accuracy?

Tags: python, machine-learning

We generally avoid train/test as the estimate will change depending on what sample we took for training and what for testing, Hence will be variance in the estimate. Then we pick up cross-validation. Won't the estimate be still biased as the model in the 2nd iteration has already seen some of the data in the first iteration? Won't there be information leak across different iterations?

```
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
>>> cross_val_score(sgd_clf, X_train, y_train_5, cv=3, 
    scoring="accuracy") array([0.96355, 0.93795, 0.95615])
```

Comment: No, the model is completely retrained for each iteration.